# The problem of deleting files on the host with the File package in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, delete-file

My host does not support the open_basedir module and I have a problem to delete the photo
I use this code to delete:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
if (File::exists($box->image))
    File::delete($box->image);
```

And it doesn't work, what method should I use to support open_basedir in the host

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
if (File::exists($box->image))
    File::delete($box->image);
>>> error: 
file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/images//Pinterest_Download (84).jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/app/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your host does support open_basedir. The error is just telling you, that you try to access a file on the disk that you are not allowed to access because of open_basedir restrictions.

It looks like your problem is, that you are trying to access the absolute path. Maybe you could try to reference the correct directory with laravels [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-app-path).

When your directory actually lays under the root path you have to switch that, as you will never get access to it when an openbasedir restriction is in effect.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
if (File::exists(storage_path($box->image))) {
  File::delete(storage_path($box->image));
}
```

Keep in mind that `storage_path()` refrences the storage/ directory inside your laravel project.